# SQL nested grouping issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's my query:

```
select
    cast(ar.AudienceCreationDate as date) as AudienceDate,
    Count(*) as [Count],
    count(case when ar.Source = 'Contact' then ar.Id end) as PatientCount,
    count(case when ar.Source = 'PatientContact' then ar.Id end) as PatientContactCount,
    (
        select 
            count(*) 
        from 
            _SMSMessageTracking sms 
        inner join 
            [CTT Preferences] pref on pref.ContactId = sms.SubscriberKey
        where 
            sms.Name <> 'ky_ctt_join' and pref.Source = 'Patient'
    ) as PatientSMS,
    (
        select 
            count(*) 
        from 
            _SMSMessageTracking sms 
        inner join 
            [CTT Preferences] pref on pref.ContactId = sms.SubscriberKey
        where 
            sms.Name <> 'ky_ctt_join' and pref.Source = 'PatientContact'
    ) as PatientContactSMS
from
    Daily_Symptom_Check_Audience_Archive ar
group by
    cast(ar.AudienceCreationDate as date)
```

And here's the result set it creates:
[image]

The issue I'm having is that the values in the rightmost two columns are the same across the board, for all records.  This number represents the TOTAL, and not aggregated by day, as the other values indicate. I realize that I'm doing something wrong - what can I do to modify my query to effectively have a proper "grouping" on these last two columns just like all the other data in this table?

Comment: You need to add in to each subquery a filter on `ar` table

Answer (score 0):

in the where clause of the nested query add `sms.AudienceDate = ar.AudienceDate`